# extrusion with threejs has wrong dimensions

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to understand how to extrude a path using threejs.
I looked at https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry
which is what I need.
Here is the code I tried:

```js
// ------------------------------------------------
// BASIC SETUP
// ------------------------------------------------
// Create an empty scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();


// Create a basic perspective camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 150;

// Create a renderer with Antialiasing
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});

// Configure renderer clear color
renderer.setClearColor("#000000");

// Configure renderer size
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

// Append Renderer to DOM
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


// ------------------------------------------------
// FUN STARTS HERE
// ------------------------------------------------

function make_graphics(){
    // clean up:
    for( var i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        obj = scene.children[i];
        scene.remove(obj); 
    }

    // Create a Shape Mesh with basic material
    const shape = new THREE.Shape();
    const x_len = 12;
    const y_len = 8;
    shape.moveTo( 0, 0 );
    shape.lineTo( 0, y_len );
    shape.lineTo( x_len, y_len );
    shape.lineTo( x_len, 0 );
    shape.lineTo( 0, 0 );

    const extrudeSettings = {
        steps: 2,
        depth: 12,
        bevelEnabled: true,
        bevelThickness: 1,
        bevelSize: 1,
        bevelOffset: 0,
        bevelSegments: 1
    };

    const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, wireframe:true } );
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) ;
    scene.add( mesh );

    // Render Loop
    var render = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame( render );

      mesh.rotation.x += 0.001;
      mesh.rotation.y += 0.001;

      // Render the scene
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    render(1, 1, 1);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    make_graphics();
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Three.js 101</title>
  <!--  Simple reset to delete the margins  -->
  <style>
    body { margin: 0; }
    canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
  </style>
  <!--  Three.js CDN  -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--  Our code  -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The extrusion is very long. It should be 12 by 8 by 12 but you can see it looks like a long rod. Does anyone know why the dimensions look wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an old version of Three.js (r83).  In that version, what became the `depth` option in `ExtrudeGeometry` was called `amount`, and it defaults to 100 if it's not present.  If you change `depth` to `amount` in your `extrudeSettings` object, or (preferably) change your CDN link to import a more recent version of Three.js, your code should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the latest threejs and it worked.